# Preventing statement in for loop from printing each iteration?

Tags: java

I have a program that takes whatever string is entered and prints it backwards. However, the statement I want to print prints after each iteration because it is in the for loop. However, when I move it outside the for loop, it doesn't recognize the variable "letter". How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadBackwards {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   String word;
   char letter;
   int counter, wordLength;

   System.out.print("Please type a word: ");
   word = keyboard.next();

   wordLength = word.length();

   for(counter = wordLength-1; counter >= 0; counter--) {

   letter = word.charAt(counter);

   System.out.print(word + " backwards is " + letter);

   }

   }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted, given that it shows code and effort.  In any case, you have two functioning answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By appending each letter to something like a `StringBuilder` and then printing that. You should also try to limit the scope of your variables (and I'm not sure I see the value in most of them). You could do

```
String word = keyboard.next();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int counter = word.length() - 1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
    sb.append(word.charAt(counter));
}
System.out.println(word + " backwards is " + sb.toString());
```

And, that might be further simplified to

```
String word = keyboard.next();
System.out.println(word + " backwards is " 
        + new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `System.out.print()` instead of `println()` and just print single characters in a single row:

```
System.out.println(word + " backwards is: ");
for (counter = wordLength-1; counter >= 0; counter--) {
    letter = word.charAt(counter);
    System.out.print(letter);
}
```

## Demo